# How to protect sqlite db in your core-data iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, iphone-security

I have a Core Data-based iPhone app with a pre-populated read-only database. What protection (if any) can I apply to my database to reduce the likelihood of piracy / the database being read off a jail-broken iPhone?

Most code examples for using a pre-populated sqlite database show the database being copied from the app bundle into the app's documents directory on the iPhone and this is completely visible on a jail-broken iPhone. Instead, I thought about using the database directly from the app bundle as follows:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: 
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
             @"MyDatabaseName.sqlite"]];

    <... followed by standard persistentStoreCoordinator code ...>
```

When I put a breakpoint on the store url this returns just another file location which I'm guessing is just as visible as the documents directory in a jail-broken iPhone:

```
<CFURL 0x139610 [0x38388ff4]>{type = 15, string = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6ACD76F0-396D-4DB1-A46B-B2459A084063/MyiPhoneApp.app/MyDatabaseName.sqlite, base = (null)}
```

Can someone please confirm if above is correct and/or if there are other ways to address this issue (I'm not looking to encrypt or anything like that ... hoping for a quick protect solution) ? Appreciate a determined hacker will get what they want -- I want to at least put up some resistance if I can.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, yes you can store a read-only database inside of your app bundle and access it directly from there.

Second, the only way to protect the data is to keep it encrypted on disk and unencrypted in memory.  This cannot easily be done using Core Data in its current form.  What you can do is to encrypt certain columns of the database and decrypt them only in memory. This is accomplished by storing the columns as binary data but that also means you cannot do any searches on those columns.

### Update

Even trying to avoid Jailbroken phones (which is not a 100% guarantee that the person is a criminal. Keep in mind that developers frequently jailbreak their phones for honest reasons). will not protect your data.  The data is sitting inside of a zip file on their desktop computer and is accessible without ever being run or touching a CocoaTouch device.

If the data is that private then you need to put it on a webservice and never store it on the device.  **Anything** on the device (or any device for that matter) is accessible and subject to reverse engineering.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Unfortunately the columns to protect have searches applied so storing as binary isn't the most feasible solution. One thought that just occurred to me is whether I can detect a jail-broken phone at start-up. If detected, I can delete the database from /var/mobile/... (or documents directory if db lives there) and just exit/not run the app at all. One variation of this is to have the database deleted from its file location at the end of each application run (add code in applicationWillTerminate) so that the database is never left on the file system. Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Having done some more thinking and researching, I agree with your update. There may be some initial measures that one can take to prevent the most basic of hack attempts -- eventually though, a determined hacker will get what they want.

Comment: Liked the answer. But unfortunately you can retrieve any data from .plist or .sqlite from iphone bundle. There is actually no way to protect the data. Encryption/decryption is good but an experienced person can do reverse engineering to get the key.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:
https://github.com/calebmdavenport/encrypted-core-data
It looks early in development but if you have a simple data model you might be able to get it working. uses sqlcipher.

You could also try Encryption Transformer class's. Can break predicates. If you use nspredicates and depending on your security needs, you can choose an encryption algorithm that preserves relative alphabetical order (roll your own if you have to). this will allow you to use predicates. the bottom of this page explains with code samples how to do it (though you'll need to find a suitable encryption algorithm as their's breaks predicates): http://blog.artlogic.com/tag/encryption/
Encrypts fields rather than the whole database.

stopping/detecting jail breaking won't stop anything. you can open the apps package file on your mac in finder without doing a jailbreak or anything special. syncing to itunes pulls your apps .ipa file down so all you need to do is go to the file and open it to get to the app's package data.